# Cannot choose correct company in Developer Story

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

There’s [“tarent solutions GmbH”](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/tarent-solutions-gmbh) in Jobs, but in my Developer Story, I can only select “tarent AG”. For some reason, these two datasets are divergent.

(That being said, they’re going to merge within the next years anyway…)

Comment: The whole company system for the developer story is a mess. My company exists three times for employees and 5 times as an education institute.